Does Flink handle state by value or by reference?
All examples I've found so far handle Flink ValueState similarly;
  private ValueState<Long> myState;

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration parameters) {
    myState = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
        "myState", Types.LONG));
  }

  @Override
  public void processElement(Integer value, Context ctx, Collector<Integer> out) {
    // Read the state
    Long stateValue = myState.value();
    if (stateValue == null) {
      // If first time, init to something
      stateValue = 0L;
    }

    // some logic
    
    // Write back to state
    myState.update(stateValue);
    out.collect(value);
  }

I don't have clear idea of what's going on in value() and update() -- is there serialization/deserialization happening there, i.e. is a copy of or reference to stateValue stored?
The difference becomes more relevant with a POJO instead of a Long:
  private static class MyPojo {
    public String name;
    public long birthday;
  }

  private ValueState<MyPojo> myState;

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration parameters) {
    myState = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
        "myState", Types.POJO(MyPojo.class)));
  }

  @Override
  public void processElement(Integer value, Context ctx, Collector<Integer> out) {
    MyPojo stateValue = myState.value();
    if (stateValue == null) {
      stateValue = new MyPojo();
      myState.update(stateValue);
    }

    // some logic

    stateValue.name = String.valueOf(value);
    stateValue.birthday = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // do I want to update() here, or is state being modified by-ref?

    out.collect(value);
  }

Is it required to update() after modifying an object I got out of state or will the changes I made to the object eventually be persisted by Flink?

You use value() to read the state for the current key. In the case of the RocksDB state backend, this is a copy created by deserializing the serialized bytes stored on disk. You are expected to call update() to write changes back.

Excellent, that's as I hoped/expected. I'm looking at some code that omits the update() most of the time, yet seems to work. Does it work by accident for the HashMapStateBackend (which is the default, right?)?

The HashMapStateBackend is the default. I'm not sure how it's implemented, exactly.

Thanks -- I did some digging, and I'm not 100% sure of the details, but it does look like the map only gets/puts object references, no explicit copying.
But my takeaway is that the abstract model is that you read state using value() and write any changes back using update() -- anything else is mostly undefined behavior. Correct?

Yes, correct. And what you say regarding the heap-based state backend may well be the case. I've seen some strange behavior which this might explain.
